What's the best way to set a field to a concatenation of a prefix and an auto incrementing field in MySQL?
I have a MySQL table with an auto-increment primary key id, and a not null unique field reference. I want to set reference equal to a prefix plus the records id, like "Prefix-1".
I tried updating reference's column to be a concat of the prefix and the id, but having a calculated column based off a auto-increment column is illegal in MySQL. I tried using a before insert trigger, setting information_schema_stats_expiry to zero and fetching the latest auto_increment value from information_schema, which works for single or sequential inserts, but multiple inserts (via insert into x values row1 row2) end up having issues as they seem to get the same auto_increment values, which from skimming MySQL docs seems intentional for the sake of reproducibility.
Fetching the last inserted record's id and adding one doesn't work since records can be deleted and the id would still have been incremented from the deleted record.
It seems like the only way is to remove the not null and unique modifiers from reference and then update it after every insert, but is there any alternative or better way I am missing?

first this column should not be not null, then you use a trigger after insert for that table. so your insert will be insert into table (col1...)... do not add the prefix col. Then in the trigger you just do an update on that row ...FOR EACH ROW SET prefixCol = concat('prefix-', :new.id); that's it.

After insert triggers cannot update values

This sounds like a good use for a generated column, not a trigger.

MySQL does not allow generated columns that are based off an auto-increment column

you are right, sorry my bad: here is an alternate solution then: https://sqlfiddle.com/mysql/online-compiler?id=7facb3bf-a769-41db-b679-1513fe969773
